# In unity editor script, how to open asset with code editor without specific file type

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I know following can open script:

```
AssetDatabase.OpenAsset(AssetDatabase.LoadAssetAtPath<MonoScript>(assetPath))
```

but if I need open a json file, or other file type file, I don't know the Type for LoadAssetAtPath how should i open this asset

can i only specific asset path and open asset with code editor?

Answer (score 0):

Use AssetDatabase.LoadMainAssetAtPath